# Normalize to Boyce Codd Normal Form in relational data model

Tags: database, normalization

OK this is probably very basic for the majority of you, but I'm struggling to do this assignment (Yep, it's homework). I've attempted this twice now and failed both times so far.

I need to create a relational data model in Boyce Codd Normal Form.
Here are the details:

> The Airport Authority in a small nation requires a database to store
> information about airlines, pilots and planes.
>
> There is only one
> airport but several airlines use it. For each airline its
> identification code and full name is required together with the phone
> number of its local office. Several types of plane use the airport and
> for each type, the fuel capacity and maximum range is to be recorded.
>
> Each pilot works for only one airline. For each pilot, their name,
> date of birth, address, the types of plane they can fly and their
> pilot‟s licence number is to be recorded. Further information is to be
> recorded to enable the production of a report listing the following
> details for each plane that uses the airport: Plane identification
> code, Plane type, Date of manufacture, Owning airline.

This is what I now have (After re-designing):

The table AIRLINES should include:

```
ID,
Name,
Phone #
```

The table PLANES should include:

```
ID,
Date of Manufacture
Airline ID
FOREIGN KEY (Airline ID) references table AIRLINES
Plane Type ID 
FOREIGN KEY (Plane Type ID) references table PLANE TYPE
```

The table PLANE TYPE should include:

```
ID,
Maximum range,
Fuel capacity,
```

The table PILOTS should include:

```
ID,
Name,
Date of Birth,
Address,
License #,
Airline ID,
FOREIGN KEY (Airline ID) references table AIRLINES
PilotPlaneID
FOREIGN KEY (PilotPlaneID) references table PILOTPLANETYPE
```

The table PILOTPLANETYPE should include:

```
   PilotID
   PlaneTypeID
   FOREIGN KEY (PilotID) references table PILOT
   FOREIGN KEY (PlaneTypeID) references table PLANE TYPE
```

According to my marker, I had have left a many to many relationship between Pilot and Plane Type.
Can someone with some database design knowledge please give me helping hand?

(EDIT: Tables now updated with PILOTPLANETYPE, which I think should satisfy the requirements)?

Comment: A type of plane is manufactured over a vast date range (20 years, maybe); the date of manufacture for a single plane is probably not associated with the type of plane but with the specific plane.  Similarly, there are many airlines that fly a given type of plane, but a given plane is only flown by a single airline at a time.  You have some attributes misplaced, therefore.

Comment: Ok, i've changed the tables and attributes. Do you think this should work now?

Comment: Pretty close; you might want to document that the combination of PilotID and PlaneTypeID is the primary key of the PilotPlaneType table.  You've got the minimum necessary information in the PlaneType table; I suspect you might want a Manufacturer ID (and table of Manufacturers to identify the different manufacturers, with a PK-FK relationship to PlaneType) and a Model Name in the PlaneType table.  Simply printing the plane type number might be sufficient, but probably isn't quite.

Comment: So if i make PilotID,PlaneTypeID a combination key, can i reference it as PilotPlaneID from the PILOTS table without creating a seperate primary key?

Comment: Four of your tables have an ID column as the (single-column) primary key.  The PilotPlaneType table should also have a primary key (saying that a particular pilot can fly a particular type of plane twice does not make it any truer).  Your Pilots table does need to reference the PilotPlaneType table; your PilotPlaneType table already references both the Pilots table and the PlaneType table (via the two foreign keys).

Answer (score 1):

Your design has one plane type per pilot.

The description contains "the types of plane they can fly".  This plural suggests that each pilot could be flying many planes.

Since this is homework, I'll let you figure out how to put this information into your design.

Comment: Ok how about if i create a table called: Pilot_plane_type with the Primary key: PilotID, PlanetypeID between Pilot and Plane Type?

Comment: I think that would satisfy the condition for reasonableness.  I don't know exactly what "Boyce Codd" normal form refers to, so I can't speak to the academic definition.

Comment: Boyce Codd Normal Form (BCNF) basically means 'sensible'.  Although there is a formal definition (and a cogent informal one: _Each attribute in the table represents a fact about the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key, so help me, Codd!_), it is basically common sense.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler . . . Once upon a time, I thought I understood normal forms when I learned about first, second, and third normal forms.  And then I see the strangest questions here about arcane normal forms.  At this point, I'm happy to settle for the practical.  And, given what I know about Codd, I do believe he was practical before all else (I'm not familiar with Boyce).